# Deploy faker data to heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, json-server

Run JS file in heroku.

I created fake data using **faker.js**

```
var faker = require('faker')
function generateEmployees () {
  var employees = []
  for (var id = 0; id < 50; id++) {
    var firstName = faker.name.firstName()
    var lastName = faker.name.lastName()
    var email = faker.internet.email()
    employees.push({
      "id": id,
      "first_name": firstName,
      "last_name": lastName,
      "email": email
    })
  }
  return { "employees": employees }
}
module.exports = generateEmployees
```

**server.js**

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);
server.listen(port);
```

**db.json**

```
{
  "posts":[
    {
      "id" : 0,
      "title": "First post!",
      "content" : "My first content!"
    }
  ],
  "comments" : [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "content": "Wow such content!",
      "username": "zero_cool"
    }
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "json-server-heroku",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "json-server,heroku, node, REST API"
  ],
  "author": "Jesper Orb",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "json-server": "^0.12.1"
  }
}
```

I deployed it in heroku.

But, I can see on two API posts and comments I can't see employees fake data on heroku.

I know I can run `json-server employees.js` locally but, don't know how to run in heroku.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently It only show three URL. I want employees also.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to run a CLI command on Heroku?

Comment: @Chris No. I want to deploy faker.js on heroku So, it create API to display employee data. Check my edited question.